# WorkFlow StateMachine в .net 4.5+

Tags: c#, .net

Сколько не искал не смог найти подробных материалов по данной технологии. Любые найденные мною тексты это различные варианты на тему Hello World по данной технологии либо описание для версий .net 3,5.

В частности интересуют вопросы создания конечных автоматов. Посоветуйте подробный гайд/книгу по данной теме...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное, что удалось найти более-менее приемлимое: Книга PRO FW 4.5 авторства Bayer White. Но там скорее введение в технологию. Обзор основных возможностей с примерами. Перевода на русский нет
Если в книге нет ответа на нужные вопросы то спасает только метод научного тыка. Иногда ещё помогают гугл и форумы.